# Help convert this jQuery.getJson to jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to reformat the function below in the form of an jQuery.ajax call in order to do error handling (the script is apparently timing out on some calls). What would this look like if converted to .ajax() with an error callback and a success callback?

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/tobacco"
    +"appid=myAppID"
    +"&lang=en"
    +"&format=json"
    +"&count=50"
    +"&view=keyterms"
    +"&callback=?",
    function (data) {
        // if no error, do something, else gracefully exit
    });
```

Comment: You can use `.ajaxError`.  http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: that will give you a global error handler, using an error: func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ url: "http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/tobacco"
    +"appid=myAppID"
    +"&lang=en"
    +"&format=json"
    +"&count=50"
    +"&view=keyterms"
    +"&callback=?", 
    success: function(data){
        //do somethign with the data
      },
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
       //do something on error
    }  
    });
```

Comment: jQuery error function doesnt work well all the time with JQuery 1.4, for a reliable implementation use try/catch. (Just in case you need error handling)

Comment: @t3ch: Can I use try/catch with my original code in my question (vs converting to .ajax as FatherStorm suggests?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 5 years later, but you probably shouldn't be constructing your own query string

```
$.ajax({ url: "http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/tobacco",
    data: {appid: "myAppID",
        lang: "en",
        format: "json",
        count: "50",
        view: "keyterms",
        callback: "?"},
    type: "GET",
    dataformat: "JSON",

    success: function(data){
        //do something with the data
    },

    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
       //do something on error
    }  
});
```